# LanguageR/ lme4: any help on p-values for models with random correlation parameters?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4

I use the package `languageR` for mixed effect models with the syntax at the end of this posting. I can use `pvals.fnc` to get *p*-values for models 1 and 3 (`hd_lmer1` and `hd_lmer2`). Using this with model two gives the following error message:

> p2 = pvals.fnc(hd_lmer2)
>   Error in pvals.fnc(hd_lmer2) : 
>     MCMC sampling is not yet implemented in lme4_0.999375
>     for models with random correlation parameters

I would be grateful if any one could help me out on how to get p-values for such models.

Models:

```
hd_lmer1 <- lmer(
  rot ~ time + group + sex + gen + (1 | subject) + (1 | rot.pre),
  data = data_long,
  REML = TRUE
)

hd_lmer2 <- lmer(
  rot ~ time + group + sex + gen + (time | subject) + (1 | rot.pre),
  data = data_long,
  REML = TRUE
)

hd_lmer3 <- lmer(
  rot ~ time * group + sex + gen + (1 | subject) + (1 | rot.pre),
  data = data_long,
  REML = TRUE
)
```

Comment: I think you would be more likely to get useful answers on the R-SIG-mixed-models mailing list

Comment: a valid question, but very domain specific to that particular package.

Answer (score -2):

It is an old post but here is one possible solution that can be helpful, using a model comparison method to test if hd_lmer2 produces a better fit than hdlmer1 (i.e., if the addition of the random effect is significative or not).

```
hdlmer1ml<-update(hdlmer1,REML=FALSE)
hdlmer2ml<-update(hdlmer2,REML=FALSE)

anova(hdlmer2ml,hdlmer1ml)
```

Comment: This is likely to be somewhat conservative because it ignores boundary issues: see http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq